# Decompiling .Net precompiled website: How can I tell which dll's hold what source code?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have several dll's in a pre-compiled website's bin directory. Are the dll's just for each individual change? Is there one dll that holds all the source code or do i have to decompile each ddl then figure if the code is currently relevant? Sorry I can't include a image of the bin directory and the files becauseI don't have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably all the DLL hold some code which in a way help the website to work. There **is** a main DLL, however it references and uses all the others, because if it wouldn't, they simply won't be there.

So, shortly **yes**, you will have to decompile all of them.

Comment: Thanks @AgentFire. I was afraid I was going to have to decompile them all.